# realloc() : realloc invalid next size and malloc(): malloc memory corruption fast

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

i am creating stack

```
typedef struct cool {
     int value; 
}arr;

typedef struct stack {
     int top;
     arr **st;
}STACK;
```

I need to create STACK dynamicall by increasing one block at a time.so i tried like this..

```
int size = 1;
STACK *mainstack;

mainstack = (STACK *) malloc (sizeof(STACK));
create(mainstack);
create(mainstack);
create(mainstack);

void create(STACK *mainstack) {
       if((mainstack = realloc(mainstack, (size + 1))) != NULL) {
               mainstack[size].st = (arr **) malloc(10 * sizeof(arr*));
        }
        ++size;
}
```

for the first time i called create() no problem..but again i reallocte by calling create() i get error like this...
realloc(): invalid next size.....

so i changed the realloc by

```
mainstack = realloc(mainstack, (size + 1) * sizeof(STACK));
```

then again i get the error like this..

malloc() : memory corruption fast

two times i called create its working good.but aftrer third call showing error..
please anyone tell me what actually behind those? Or Is there any other way to fulfill my thoughts without getting these error..

Comment: `mainstack` in `create` is a copy of `mainstack` in the caller function. Changing its value does not change the value of the original.

Comment: And given the definition of `STACK`, its size is fixed. What you should `realloc` (and, `malloc()` first), is the member `st` of your `STACK`.

Comment: And what is this `size` actual representing? Number of stack entries? Then `sizeof(*mainstack)` multiplication is missing when doing allocation

Comment: Not trying to be rude here, but it's a *complete mess* and chaos. I suggest you find a good introduction to read, be sure it tells you something about the difference between arrays and pointers. I would not try to fix *this* code.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot work:

```
void create(STACK *mainstack){
  if ((mainstack = realloc(mainstack, (size + 1))) != NULL) {
    mainstack[size].st = (arr **)malloc(10 * sizeof(arr*));
  }
  ++size;
}
```

`mainstack = realloc(mainstack...` modifies the *local* variable `mainstack` which will go out of scope at the end of the function.

So after `create(mainstack);`, `mainstack` will remain un changed.

Simple example:

```
void foo(int bar)
{
  bar = 2;
}
...

int x = 123;
foo(x);
// x contains 123 and n ot 2
```

You need this for example:

```
STACK *create(STACK *mainstack){
  if ((mainstack = realloc(mainstack, (size + 1))) != NULL) {
    mainstack[size].st = (arr **)malloc(10 * sizeof(arr*));
  }
  ++size;

  return mainstack;
}

int main()
{
  int size = 1;
  STACK *mainstack;

  mainstack = malloc(sizeof(STACK));
  mainstack = create(mainstack);
  mainstack = create(mainstack);
  mainstack = create(mainstack);
}
```

That said, the overall design using the global variable `size` is not very good and the error handling in `create` is bogous.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to create a dynamically growing stack and you already have an answer explaining you where you went wrong with your code. Still the design seems a bit complicated, therefore I'll show you some commented code of a solution I'd consider *straight forward*, using only a single `struct`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Stack
{
    size_t capacity;  // how many items the stack can hold right now
    size_t index;     // index of the first unused element
                      // (kind of a "stack pointer")
    int stack[];      // the elements, variable length
} Stack;

Stack *Stack_create(size_t n)
{
    // create stack with room for `n` elements
    Stack *self = malloc(sizeof(Stack) + n * sizeof(int));
    // you need to add `n * sizeof(int)` here for the flexible array member

    if (!self) exit(1);
    self->capacity = n;
    self->index = 0;
    return self;
}

void Stack_destroy(Stack *self)
{
    if (!self) return;
    free(self);
}

void Stack_push(Stack **self, int val)
{
    Stack *s = *self;
    if (s->index == s->capacity)
    {
        // if necessary, double the number of elements the stack can hold
        s->capacity *= 2;
        s = realloc(s, sizeof(Stack) + s->capacity * sizeof(int));
        if (!s) exit(1);
        *self = s;
    }
    s->stack[s->index++] = val;
}

int Stack_pop(Stack *self, int *val)
{
    if (self->index)
    {
        *val = self->stack[--self->index];
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    Stack *stack = Stack_create(5);

    Stack_push(&stack, 47);
    Stack_push(&stack, 12);
    Stack_push(&stack, 73);
    Stack_push(&stack, 5);
    Stack_push(&stack, 13);
    Stack_push(&stack, 23);

    int val;
    while (Stack_pop(stack, &val))
    {
        printf("%d ", val);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    Stack_destroy(stack);

    return 0;
}
```

Notes about this:

- Error checking on `malloc()` and `realloc()` is minimal here for brevity. In practice, there's of course not much you can do, and maybe `exit(1)` is enough, but if your program is more complex, you might want to return an error to the caller instead, so it could e.g. `fflush()` files etc.
- You typically want to avoid a *lot* of `realloc()` calls (they can be expensive). Allocating some space in advance and doubling the space if more is needed is a common approach for such data structures.
- If you don't like having to pass a double pointer to `Stack_push()`, you must indeed use a pointer instead of the flexible array member like this:

  ```
  typedef struct Stack
  {
      size_t capacity;
      size_t index;
      int *stack;
  } Stack;
  ```

  Then you have to allocate space for this with a separate call to `malloc()` and need your `realloc` only on this member.